# Multi-dimensional array concatenation on module port

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying concatenation of several packed arrays to unpacked array

```
module temp (
 output logic         [64-1:0]   top_fab_diu_tmu_time_o_0,
 output logic         [64-1:0]   top_fab_diu_tmu_time_o_1,
 output logic         [64-1:0]   top_fab_diu_tmu_time_o_2,
);

temp_v1 u_temp_v1 (
   . top_fab_diu_tmu_time ({top_fab_diu_tmu_time_o_0,top_fab_diu_tmu_time_o_1,top_fab_diu_tmu_time_o_2})
);
```

where module `temp_v1` port is defined as unpacked array:

```
module temp_v1 (
   output logic [63:0] top_fab_diu_tmu_time [3],
);
```

**when i run ace compilation (vcs) it failed and generate this error message:**

> Unpacked array concatenation to output port will be treated as
> assignment ;;  pattern. Prefix with tick (') to convert to assignment
> pattern.

However DC next (Design compiler) PASS

**when i change the port assignment on module temp to (add '):**

```
.top_fab_diu_tmu_time('{top_fab_diu_tmu_time_o_0,top_fab_diu_tmu_time_o_1,top_fab_diu_tmu_time_o_2})
```

VCS compilation- PASS

DC nxt - FAILED with this message:

> The construct 'assignment pattern in port connection' is not supported

Answer (score 0):

Since your tools are struggling with this syntax, you can declare another signal to connect directly to the instance port, then `assign` each 64-bit output separately:

```
module temp (
 output logic         [64-1:0]   top_fab_diu_tmu_time_o_0,
 output logic         [64-1:0]   top_fab_diu_tmu_time_o_1,
 output logic         [64-1:0]   top_fab_diu_tmu_time_o_2
);

logic [63:0] top_fab_diu_tmu_time [3];
temp_v1 u_temp_v1 (.top_fab_diu_tmu_time (top_fab_diu_tmu_time));

    assign top_fab_diu_tmu_time_o_0 = top_fab_diu_tmu_time[0];
    assign top_fab_diu_tmu_time_o_1 = top_fab_diu_tmu_time[1];
    assign top_fab_diu_tmu_time_o_2 = top_fab_diu_tmu_time[2];
endmodule
```

This compiles for me on VCS without errors or warnings.

Comment: suince our BE tools translate these assign to buffer , we want to avoid from assigns. is there any way to avoid these assigns? (we prefer not to have assigns)

Comment: yes , it compiles , but we prefer no to use this way :(

Comment: @IdanRahamim I do not think that you have any other choice in this case. Have you tried to switch to a multi-dimensional **packed** array: `logic [63:0][3] top_fab_diu_tmu_time`

Comment: Hi, tnx for reply. Prefer way that don't require to change the interface of temp_v1.. I want that interface will remain unpacked array

Comment: talk to synopsys then.